# Show only “Read more” link in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, themes, customization, drupal-8, teaser

How can I show only **read more** link, and remove or unset other links like "add new comments" or "2 Comments" at the end of a node teaser?

Comment: Have you tried doing something for yourself first?

Comment: yes, I'm try doing somting for myself.

Comment: Then, please, update your post with what you've done so far.

Comment: I Foud a soluton here: [link](http://http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192878/show-only-read-more-link/192886?noredirect=1#comment232876_192886) **But doesn't work properly**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have custom links, you need the **links--node.html.twig** template file, it does theme override to display node links.

**1.**
Paste this:

```
This is links.html.twig talking.... 
{% if links -%}
  {%- if heading -%}
    {%- if heading.level -%}
      <{{ heading.level }}{{ heading.attributes }}>{{ heading.text }}</{{ heading.level }}>
    {%- else -%}
      <h2{{ heading.attributes }}>{{ heading.text }}</h2>
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endif -%}
  <ul{{ attributes }}>
    {%- for key, item in links -%}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(key|clean_class) }}>
        {%- if item.link -%}
          {{ item.link }}
        {%- elseif item.text_attributes -%}
          <span{{ item.text_attributes }}>{{ item.text }}</span>
        {%- else -%}
          {{ item.text }}
        {%- endif -%}
      </li>
    {%- endfor -%}
  </ul>
{%- endif %}
```

into your editor

**2.**  Customise at will.

**3.** save as **themes/YOUR_THEME/templates/links.html.twig**

**4.** clear cache

**5.** See it in action

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I have such as this file in my templates directory in my theme folder as Default, but I do not know how to customize it, Can you help me to reach my goals with give more information about this problem.

Comment: Since it would be your next step, I suggest you to post a new question providing what you expect the links--node.html.twig should produce. In the meantime, thanks for feedback on my reply.